# SimpleXML seems to not load anything...?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

This is really baffling me. I've never used XML before, so I'm just playing about (it's the middle of the night of course...!)

The code:

```
$xml_string = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><result>
    <status>fail</status>
    <error>
        <code>192</code>
        <message>Previous command still being processing</message>
    </error>
</result>"
$rss = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
print $rss->result->status;
```

I'm kinda baffled... Every tutorial that I have read seems to suggest that this will print "fail" - but yet it doesn't...? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some errors:

- You are quoting your string in double
  quotes but there are unescaped double
  quotes inside the string which
  prematurely terminate your string. To
  fix this either escape the double
  quotes inside the string or use
  single quote or here doc.
- The `result` node is the root of the
  document so to print `fail` you need:

  ```
  print $rss->status;
  ```

[**See it**](http://codepad.org/jahFGUg8)

As a tip you can always dump the content of the XML object by doing `print_r($rss);`

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. it wasn't actually the unescaped quotes, they only emerged when I was trying to use the code snippet thing here on stackoverflow! My problem was, as you identified, the print $rss->status; where I was using print $rss->result->status;